# How hard is it to decide if there exists a strict improvement of a given solution of an NP-complete problem?

Tags: optimization, np-complete, decision-problem, set-cover

Take the Set Cover problem as an example. When we ask if there is a set of size k that covers all the elements, the problem is NP-complete. Now if we ask, for a given set $S$ of size $k$, if there exists another set that covers strictly more elements than $S$ does. Is this problem still NP-complete?

To be clearer, let's think about the Set Cover problem as an optimization problem: what is the maximum number of elements that can be covered by $k$ sets. The decision version is: are there $k$ sets that cover at least $m$ elements? (where $m$ is part of the input, and the version you were saying is simply the special case when $m=n$). Now the problem is, for $k$ given sets (as part of the input), does there exist $k$ other sets that cover strictly more elements than the $k$ given sets do.

Comment: duplicate of (https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/41570/how-hard-is-it-to-decide-if-there-exists-a-strict-improvement-of-a-given-solutio)

Comment: What are your thoughts on the question? Have you tried proving NP-hardness?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, I tried but without success. What I know is if it is required to give a witness when the answer is yes, then starting from a random solution and repeatedly asking if there's any other solution strictly better, we are able to reach the optimal solution in at most n steps (n being the number of elements in the set cover problem), which gives an answer to the set cover problem. However, if this is not required, I have no idea.

Comment: @ThinhD.Nguyen, yes, I posted there but no response so I reposed here. Should I delete that one? I'm not very familiar with the rules. Sorry.

Comment: @user2477759 Witnesses appear when proving that problems are in NP; your problem is in NP, since the witness is a better cover. The hard part is proving NP-hardness. Perhaps you should first make sure you have a solid understanding of how these proofs go.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, yes, it is in NP. I was just trying to answer an easier question: if some algorithm solves the problem I proposed and in particular gives a witness when the answer is yes, then we can solve Set Cover problem by calling this algorithm polynomially many times.

Comment: I'm not really clear what you mean. Since S covers all elements, no set can cover strictly more than all elements, right?

Comment: @gnasher729, OK, maybe it's not very clear. Let's think about the Set Cover problem as an optimization problem: what is the maximum number of elements that can be covered by k sets. The decision version is: are there k sets that cover at least m elements? (where m is part of the input, and the version you were saying is simply the special case when m=n). Now the problem I'm thinking about is, for k given sets (as part of the input), do there exist k other sets that cover strictly more elements than the k given sets do. Hope this is clearer.

Comment: "Strictly more elements" - are you talking about numbers or about a superset? Be clear. And  no need to write comments, edit your question to make it clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a reduction from Set Cover to your problem. Let $(\{S_1,\ldots,S_m\},k)$ be an instance of Set Cover, and let $U = S_1 \cup \cdots \cup S_m$. Let $x_1,\ldots,x_k$ be $k$ new elements, and consider the following instance of your problem:

- The sets are $S_i \cup \{x_j\}$ for $i \in [m]$ and $j \in [k]$, together with the set $U$.
- The given cover consists of $S_1 \cup \{x_j\}$ for $j \in [k-1]$ together with $U$.

The given cover covers all elements but $x_k$. There is a cover which covers more elements – that is, all elements – iff $U$ can be covered by at most $k$ sets from $S_1,\ldots,S_m$.